# Styling WPF controls inline with Infragistics themes

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, styles, infragistics

we are using Infragistics WPF controls (e.g. xamDataGrid, xamDockManager etc), and we will be using the Infragistics Office 2007 Blue theme which these controls support.

We also want to style the rest of the application (i.e. standard WPF controls) using the same Office 2007 Blue style.

What's the best approach? Are there Office 2007 themes/skins that we can download or purchase? Can we use anything from the Infragistics download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC for winforms infragistics allow you to use the app stylist to be able to theme the standard controls.

Just had a quick look on the forums and it doesn't look like it can be done for WPF.

[How to apply themes to non-Infragistics controls](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/3663/19032.aspx#19032)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but maybe little update can be helpful for anyone that stumbles upon this. It is working in current version of Infragistics. Resource in `App.xaml` in enough. Sources point to folder in solution that contains files from Infragistics themes (usually something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Infragistics\2015.1\WPF\Themes`).

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Theme/Styles.Shared.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Theme/Styles.WPF.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Theme/Theme.Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Theme/IG.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```